# Proof by contradiction : $n^3 −n−6 = 0$ means $m^3 − m − 6 ≠ 0$ when $m≠n$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I have to prove by contradiction that if $n$ is a positive integer such as $n^3-n-6 = 0$, so for any positive integer $m$ such as $m ≠ n$, we have $m^3-m-6 ≠ 0$

I am new to proofs, but I tried and here is what I did.

I first assume the opposite of the conclusion, so
$m^3-m-6 = 0$

$(m-2)(m^2+2m+3) = 0$

m=2

If I do the same thing for the n function and find the solution for $n^3-n-6 = 0, n=2$.

This is a contradiction since $m=n$, but we said $m ≠ n$.

I feel like im doing something wrong here and I would like someone to tell me what it is ! (Again, I am a beginner)

Comment: You can show that $n \mapsto n^3 - n - 6$ is an increasing function for $n \ge 1$, so it equals zero at most once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $n$ is a positive integer such that $n^3 − n − 6 = 0$, then, for every positive integer $m$ with $m \not = n$, $m^3 − m − 6 \not = 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141843/if-n-is-a-positive-integer-such-that-n3-%e2%88%92-n-%e2%88%92-6-0-then-for-every-positi)

Comment: You are doing fine. If anything you are doing it twice for no real reason: once you have shown that, under the condition $x\in\Bbb N$, it holds that $(x-2)(x^2+2x+3)=0$ *if and only if* $x=2$, you have shown the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your proof would be assuming $n^{3}-n-6=0, m\neq n$ (where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$) showing a contradiction if we had $m^{3}-m-6=0$ as well. You have shown by factoring and the fact that $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, that $m, n = 2$. Hence  $m=n$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct, but you're not actually using contradiction and it's indeed hard to write a *real* proof by contradiction of this particular statement.

What you proved is that if $n^3-n-6=0$, then $n=2$. Hence for no $m\ne2$ one can have $m^3-m-6=0$.

Comment: how should I proceed if I want to prove by contradiction ?

Comment: @Rewind You can fake it: suppose $m^3-m-6=0$ and $m\ne2$. Then $m=2$, contradiction. But it's a bit silly, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$n^3-n-6=0\iff$$
$$(n-1)n(n+1)=1.2.3 \iff n=2$$

thus

$$(m-1)m(m+1)\ne 6 \iff m\ne 2$$